# Animate Background window when opening BottomSheet

Tags: react-native

Building an app with RN, and while I can easily use BottomSheet view `"@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",` I cannot find how to animate the background container like most iOS apps do while opening the BottomSheet. Is there a prop I am missing?
Has anyone been able to do this?

Attaching image for reference:

[image]

Edit for more context:
What I want to achieve is the main app container animating/skewing like its shown in the attached screenshot. the bottomsheet animates from the bottom, while the main app container animates to appear like cascading cards.
the image attached is from the slack mobile app.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props#animated-nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Intuition

To get the expected background animation, I have followed following steps,

1. Create a Parent view, add an animated view and a bottom sheet modal inside this parent view.
2. Animated view will be the background on which we will add the animation
3. and, will use bottom sheet to show the content.
4. To animate the background, add *scaleX* and *scaleY* in animated view styling
5. On modal open, scale values to 0.9 or something of your choice
6. On modal close, scale values back to 1.
7. Default scaleX, scaleY value is 1

### Code

Below is the working code, you may tweak it to your liking,

```
import React, {useCallback, useMemo, useRef} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';
import {BottomSheetModal, BottomSheetModalProvider} from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import {GestureHandlerRootView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {useSharedValue, withTiming} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const App = () => {
  // shared values for scaling animation
  const scaleX = useSharedValue(1);
  const scaleY = useSharedValue(1);
  // ref to open/close modal
  const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);

  // callbacks
  const handlePresentModalPress = useCallback(() => {
    handleOpen();
    bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present();
  }, []);

  // function to call on modal open
  const handleOpen = () => {
    scaleX.value = withTiming(0.9);
    scaleY.value = withTiming(0.95);
  };

  // function to call on modal close
  const handleClose = () => {
    scaleX.value = withTiming(1);
    scaleY.value = withTiming(1);
  };

  // renders
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <BottomSheetModalProvider>
        <View style={styles.container}>  
          <Animated.View style={[styles.screen, {
            transform: [{scaleX}, {scaleY}]   // added shared values in animated view style
          }]}>
            <Button
              onPress={handlePresentModalPress}
              title="Present Modal"
              color="black"
            />
          </Animated.View>
          <BottomSheetModal
            enablePanDownToClose={false}
            ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
            handleComponent={() => (
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: 'grey',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  padding: 20,
                  borderTopRightRadius: 12,
                  borderTopLeftRadius: 12,
                }}>
                <Text>New Message</Text>
                <Text
                  onPress={() => {
                    handleClose();
                    bottomSheetModalRef.current?.dismiss();
                  }}
                  style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: 30,
                    color: 'white',
                  }}>
                  X
                </Text>
              </View>
            )}
            index={0}
            snapPoints={['95%']}>
            <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
              <Text>Awesome </Text>
            </View>
          </BottomSheetModal>
        </View>
      </BottomSheetModalProvider>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  screen: {
    height: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
});

export default App;
```

### Screenshot

[image: expected output screenshot]

Hope this answers your question,
please add a comment if you have any doubt

Comment: please let me know if this answers your question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useBottomSheetSpringConfigs` to perform an animation. Please check the following [link](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/hooks/#usebottomsheetspringconfigs) for more details.

Comment: the animation is not the issue. do you see how the background app container animates/skews inwards when the bottom sheet opens? this is a screenshot of slack, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `modal` for it, because if you don't, trying to animate the main container having the `BottomSheet` inside it will end up animating the BottomSheet as well.

In this case, you will need to use [bottom-sheet modal](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/modal/props).

Using the library code as an example:

```js
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import {
  BottomSheetModal,
  BottomSheetModalProvider,
} from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';

const App = () => {
  // ref
  const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);

  // variables
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%'], []);

  // callbacks
  const handlePresentModalPress = useCallback(() => {    
    
    /*
      [*] Here you will make your animation based on the bottomSheetModalRef.current variable, like as follows:
      if(bottomSheetModalRef.current){
        //Out animation
      } else {
        //Intro animation
      }
    */

    bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present();
  }, []);
  const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
    console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
  }, []);

  // renders
  return (
    <BottomSheetModalProvider>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          onPress={handlePresentModalPress}
          title="Present Modal"
          color="black"
        />
        <BottomSheetModal
          ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
          index={1}
          snapPoints={snapPoints}
          onChange={handleSheetChanges}
        >
          <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
            <Text>Awesome </Text>
          </View>
        </BottomSheetModal>
      </View>
    </BottomSheetModalProvider>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

I can't really test this since I don't have an app set-up, but using the `handlePresentModalPress` function, you can detect when the modal is opened or closed.
After that, you will just need to animate the `main container`, which is the parent `View` that has all the components you want to animate.

For the animation, you could use something like `transform([{scaleX: '1.25'}, {scaleZ: '1.25'}]);` for intro and `transform([{scaleX: '1'}, {scaleZ: '1'}]);` for outro.